# hyperref does not create links for expex

Tags: hyperref, expex

I used `hyperref` together with `expex` before and all was fine. Not sure when and what broke, but I don't get hyperlinks anymore, nor any idea where to look for the source of this grief. I'm compiling with `lualatex`, but `pdflatex` gives exactly the same result. Here's a MNWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[luatex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,expex,hyperref}
\gathertags %for forward refs
\begin{document}
Forward reference: (\getref{test}).\pagebreak

The ex:
\ex<test>Does the expex get a hyperlink?\xe
\pagebreak

Backward reference: (\getref{test}).
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any documented changes that would have affected this but I think you can do something like the following to add a hyperref anchor at `\ex` and make a link in the reference.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,expex,hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\ex@c{%
   \ex@setup
   \leavevmode
\ifx\@optionaltag\@empty\else
\hypertarget{expex.\@optionaltag}{}%
\fi
   \setbox\numbox=\hbox{\hskip\lingnumoffset\ep@actualexnoprint}%
   \epd@numright=\wd\numbox
   \ifcase\ep@textanchor                          % numleft
         \ep@settosum\leftskip\lingnumoffset\lingtextoffset
      \or                                         % normal
         \ep@settosum\leftskip\epd@numright\lingtextoffset
      \fi
   \llap{\hbox to\leftskip{\unhbox\numbox \hss}}%
   \lingeveryex
   \latex@tagex
   \ignorespaces
}

\def\getref#1{\def\expexrefname{#1}\getref@a{#1}\getref@aa}

\let\old@printref\@printref
%oops \def\@printref#1{\hyperlink{expex.expecrefname}{\old@printref{#1}}}
\def\@printref#1{\hyperlink{expex.\expexrefname}{\old@printref{#1}}}


\makeatother
\begin{document}


This is a test of hyperref with expex.\footnote{The former should make hyperlinks for the latter's labels.}
\ex<test>
Does the expex get a hyperlink?
\xe

This must be a hyperlink, but it isn't: (\getref{test}).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great! Two 'but's though: I get a warning that " (pdf backend): unreferenced destination with name 'expex.expecrefname'", and the link does not send me to the anchor (checked over a `\pagebreak`). And it doesn't pick up forward reference at all (prints the tag name instead of label). Do you think this can be helped?

Comment: @IvanKapitonov expex doesn't seem to support forward references at all, it does not use the aux file and just seems to use a macro, so even without hyperref  if you move the getref before the \ex then it fails as far as I can see, but i don't know the package at all. I just did the link type in your example there are probably more expex links that need to be made hyperref aware, but probably should be done by someone who knows what the package is doing.

Comment: Oh boy, I'm sorry, I was sure that my `\gathertags` is "somewhere in the preamble file" -- fixed the code in the question. That's a macro that "turns" forward reference "on" -- you're right, it doesn't use the `.aux`, but rather creates a `-tags.tex` file for that. Now I can see that if I have a link on the previous page, and a link on the page that follows the example, the first link sends me to the last one. It could be a hint to the anchor problem -- but unfortunately I've no idea what in your code is _the anchor_..

Comment: Oh I'm missing a `\ ` !!! `expexrefname` was supposed to have a backslash in so `\hyperlink{expex.expecrefname}{`  links to the anchor made here \hypertarget{expex.\@optionaltag}{}%` I'll fix...

Comment: @IvanKapitonov try now

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Now it does the job -- it still sends _just below_ the desired line, but I'll see if I can educate myself on hyperlinks and tinker with that. I'm also logging an issue on John's github page, just in case he overlooks it here.