# How do I get hyperref to play with expex and so getref is hyperlinked to the deftag

Tags: hyperref, expex

How do I get hyperref to allow me to link to individual examples created using expex (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex).

I am aware of a \label based workaround, however my full document has too many example sentences to allow retrofitting (a few thousand)

The behaviour I desire is that hyperref will allow me to click on the example reference and it will link it to the example in question.

Here is a minimal example of my usage,  any pointers or suggestions appreciated!

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\gathertags

\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is a bunch of text! and now there's an example (\getref{adj-predicates}).

\ex \deftagex{adj-predicates}
\begingl
\gla This way please. //
\glft `Bitte hier entlang' \trailingcitation source //
\endgl
\xe

Here is another bit of text and one more example (\getref{ex2}). (\getfullref{ex2.a})  is much better than (\getref{adj-predicates}).

\pex[nopreamble=true] \deftagex{ex2}
\a
\begingl
\gla Oh no! \deftaglabel{b} //
\glft `Oh nein!' \trailingcitation source1 //
\endgl
\a
\begingl
\gla I'm sorry! \deftaglabel{a} //
\glft `Es tut mir leid.' \trailingcitation source2 //
\endgl
\xe


\end{document}
```

Comment: i have read this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318497/hyperref-does-not-create-links-for-expex however the links it created were dead and it cut off the next few characters of the surrounding text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the patching method in the link that you provided, but it did not work for me either.  [Also, I had a similar issue because I wanted to use `\pageref`, but the solution provided only worked for `\getref` and not `\getfullref` also.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509881/78866)

Fortunately, I was able to get both working by patching two commands: `\deftag` and `\ep@putlabel@b`.

The first is the one that fixes `\getref`.  The second is required for `\getfullref` because it deals with each `expex` part in `\pex`...`\xe` defined by `\a`.

The key benefit here is what you were requesting: no need for `\deftagex` or `\deftaglabel`

The fix I am providing gives you two options.  First, you can create *new* commands to keep the old `\getref` and `\getfullref` functionality (This method is safer, but requires a find/replace wherever you want they hyperlinks).  Second, you can globally patch the commands so that they will *all* behave with the hyperlinks.  I present the first option in comments above the second option in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\gathertags

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\deftag{\hypertarget{#2}{}\label{#2}}{}{\fail}%
\patchcmd{\ep@putlabel@b}
    {\deftaglabel{\@optionaltag}}
    {\hypertarget{\@localextag.\@optionaltag}{}\label{\@localextag.\@optionaltag}\deftaglabel{\@optionaltag}}
    {}
    {\fail}%

%% Version 1: SAFE method - new methods for hyperlinking
%\def\gethyperref#1{\hyperlink{#1}{\getref{#1}}}%
%\def\getfullhyperref#1{\hyperlink{#1}{\getfullref{#1}}}%

%% Version 2: UNSAFE - overwrite \getref and \getfull ref globally
\let\old@getref\getref
\def\getref#1{\hyperlink{#1}{\old@getref{#1}}}%
\let\old@getfullref\getfullref
\def\getfullref#1{\hyperlink{#1}{\old@getfullref{#1}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is a bunch of text! and now there's an example (getref=\getref{adj-predicates}) (getfullref=\getfullref{adj-predicates}).  Next page has (getref=\getref{ex2}) and (getfullref=\getfullref{ex2.A})--(getfullref=\getfullref{ex2.B}).

\ex<adj-predicates>
    \begingl
        \gla This way please. //
        \glft `Bitte hier entlang' \trailingcitation source //
    \endgl
\xe

\clearpage

Here is another bit of text and one more example (getref=\getref{ex2}). (getfullref=\getfullref{ex2.A})--(getfullref=\getfullref{ex2.B})  is much better than (getref=\getref{adj-predicates}) on previous page.

\pex<ex2>
    \a<A>
        \begingl
            \gla Oh no! //
            \glft `Oh nein!' \trailingcitation source1 //
        \endgl
    \a<B>
        \begingl
            \gla I'm sorry! //
            \glft `Es tut mir leid.' \trailingcitation source2 //
        \endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

Page one:
[image: expex pg1 with hyperlinking]

Page two:
[image: expex pg2 with hyperlinking]

If you don't want to use `etoolbox` for whatever reason, you'll need to copy and paste the entire definitions for `\deftag` and `\ep@putlabel@b` from `expex` and redefine them with the patches.

Lastly, I tested with XeLaTeX.  The links worked for me in the default TeXworks (for MiKTeX), Adobe Acrobat, and SumatraPDF.  I assume this should work in general, but I have not tested it exhaustively.

Comment: Note that with version 2, `\nextx` and friends will still not be links.